# Is wxHTTP::getinputstream() threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

So i have a function to download a HTML file. And as it takes a significant amount of time, i've put it in a separate thread that works on the background and the program remains responsive. When i call the function from the main thread it works fine. But calling from the other thread causes getinputstream() to always return NULL.
so, what is causing this? and how do i fix this?
PS, i'm using wxwidgets 2.8 on Visual Studio 10.

Comment: I think here is similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067056/wxhttp-threads

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `wxHTTP::Initialize()` in main thread (not only in `wxApp:onInit()`). Blatantly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067056/wxhttp-threads) just so that question is answered.